# VS2013 cannot load ajaxcontroltoolkit

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

I get this error when I try to run a project in VS2013

> Could not load file or assembly  'AjaxControlToolkit,
>   Version=3.0.20820.18620, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' or one of its dependencies. Access is
>   denied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, the identity pool you are using to run this application does not have write access to .NET Temp Internet file. Remember you code run under there, not where you have source code. If you grant access to the .NET version/temp file you should be able to run the application. It could be AjaxControlTookit was the first dll it is loading hence throwing that exception but not an issue with the ddl itself.

Comment: That was it. I was giving permission to the bin directory but when i gave the apppool permission to the TEMP folder, that worked. Thanks